# Is ''I digress'' an idiomatic expression?

Tags: phrase-usage

I read that "I digress" is used when you realise that you were digressing. "Sorry, I was digressing" or "Sorry, I digressed" seem more grammatically appropriate to me. Is "I digress" an idiomatic expression"?

Comment: You are asking if it's natural-sounding?

Comment: I think you'll find your answer here - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167248/what-does-the-idiom-phrase-but-i-digress-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, idiomatic, but rather "stilted" and perhaps old-fashioned.

Sure,  "I was digressing" might be more "logical", but that is not how it is usually used as a discourse marker in a speech.

"I digress" should probably be used rarely.  If you are giving an after-dinner speech, it may be useful.  It's not likely to be useful in general conversation or in writing.